# Display the name of a user using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

What I want to do is to make a top header in the app with the name of the user displayed in a label. I know everything to do this except how to reference their name. To give more clarity this is what I want (even though this doesn't work in the newest version of xcode);

```
let userName = Auth.auth().currentUser.name
// so this is the string of the users name
```

I know this seems really simple and there is probably an easy way to do it that I'm not sure of. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I access my firebase realtime database and read from it:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()

ref.child("Username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
   let userName = snapshot.value as? String
   Print(userName)
}
```

Instead of where I put "Username", you can replace this with the name of the node under which the value you want to output is stored. And if this node is the child node of another, you can continue to add .child("XXX") to the line of code.

e.g.

```
ref.child("Account").child("Username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
```

Comment: I'm curious how this is relevant to the question, since it doesn't say anything about the use of Realtime Database. It's talking about Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It's tucked away a little, in [providerData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User?authuser=0#declaration_3), which is an instance of [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/UserInfo.html?authuser=0#displayname)...

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
let userName = user.providerData.displayName
```